# Copying a file only once in puppet

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet, I am trying to copy a file to remote server for installation of  a package, This file would get deleted a few minutes after installation. Is there a way to copy this file only once.? like the example below.

```
class absent_file {

  file { '/tmp/hello-file':
    ensure  => 'present',
    replace => 'no',
    content => "From Puppet\n",
    mode    => '0644',
    once    => true
  }

}
```

Comment: There are ways to do this, but first there is a threshold question: *why* do you want to do it?  You mention package installation, but if you're talking about an installation tarball then you would be better off in just about every way if you instead used a `Package` resource to ensure the wanted package installed.

Comment: I already, used the package resource. I am trying to copy a file that would be deleted once the agent-server authentication is done. This step would be done post installation (after 15 to 20 mins). I have a manifest the copies the file to the remote server but the since the file gets deleted after agent-server authentication. Puppet is created the file after every since run because its unable to find the file

Comment: You have not answered my "why" question, other than by reiterating what is already presented in the question.  If you want an answer appropriate for your circumstances then we need to understand the circumstances.

Comment: "Why do i want to do it ? " : To maintain idempotency. Right now every puppet run is creating that file that the agent uses for authentication, Although authentication is complete and the file isn't required post initial authentication. I do not want puppet to copy the file in every single puppet run. I am looking for a way to doing it once. I hope I made myself clear. something like "run once" in ansible

Comment: Evidently we are having a failure to communicate here.  I am asking about the context and bigger picture, not about your philosophy.  In any event, Puppet does not maintain records of which resources have ever been applied.  It determines what to do based on the current state of your system.  The *easiest* thing to do would be simply to not remove the file, so that Puppet can use the presence (and maybe the content) of the file to determine whether to download a fresh copy.

Comment: thanks that helps. I am sorry for being explicit about the situation. I tried to explain without disclosing any confidential information.

Comment: to achieve what you want, instead of deleting purge the file and set puppet  'replace' file attribute to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have figured out how to do it. Instead of using the file module, I ended up using command and touching another which would not get deleted along with installation process. The key can be deleted but the `somefile.txt` would be still present and the process would become idempotent.

```
exec {'add key':
  command => "echo 'SharedKeyfile' > /key/location && touch /key/location/somefile.txt'",
  onlyif  => "test ! -f /key/location/somefile.txt",    
}
```